# How to send multiple http requests python

Tags: python, python-2.7, request, python-requests, grequests

I am using python `request.post()` to send data to a remote database. How should I send more than one request(around 20-30) on same URL using different data using python ?

Also, will sequential work fine for this case or do I need to make the requests in parallel ?

Comment: You can use a `for loop`

Comment: What do you mean by one than one? More than one sequentially? In parallel? Reusing parameters, what?

Comment: @AnishShah Ok, and then how do I receive response from each request ? I mean does the loop wait till I get a response from each individual request ?

Comment: @bitgeeky you can append to a list..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) which uses [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and gevent

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://www.heroku.com',
    'http://python-tablib.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
grequests.map(rs)
[<Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>]
```